# Problem with {@link } documentation tags using Intellij and Gradle groovydoc task

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, hyperlink, groovydoc

I am trying to create documentation for a Groovy library using Intellij (2109.3.3) with a Gradle build using the groovydoc task in the Gradle window.

The structure of the library is as follows:

[image]

The component used (AnyGroupOfPipelineCollects) is just one example, becasue none of the {@link } tags work in any of the documentation I have created.

The start of the class is as follows:

```
package GPP_Library.functionals.composites

import GPP_Library.CompositeDetails
import GPP_Library.ResultDetails
import GPP_Library.functionals.pipelines.OnePipelineCollect
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovyJCSP.PAR
import jcsp.lang.CSProcess
import jcsp.lang.ChannelInput
import jcsp.lang.ChannelOutput

/**
 * An AnyGroupOfPipelineCollects comprises a network of {@code groups} parallel occurrences and each pipeline comprises
 * {@code stages} Worker processes, excluding the final {@link GPP_Library.terminals.Collect Collect} stage.
 * Inputs from the preceding process are assumed to come from the any end of a channel.
 * Internally, a collection of
 * {@code groups} {@link GPP_Library.functionals.pipelines.OnePipelineCollect OnePipeLineCollect} pipelines are created.
 *
```

Once the Gradle groovydoc task has been executed the constructed documentation is as follows:

An AnyGroupOfPipelineCollects comprises a network of **groups** parallel occurrences and each pipeline comprises **stages** Worker processes, excluding the final GPP_Library.terminals.Collect stage. Inputs from the preceding process are assumed to come from the any end of a channel. Internally, a collection of **groups** GPP_Library.functionals.pipelines.OnePipelineCollect pipelines are created.

As can be seen the expected transformation of the links into Collect and OnePipelineCollect as hypertext terms has not happened, even though the {@code} tags have been processed correctly.

Additionally, as one types the link package.class element, Intellij recognises incorrect formulations until they are correct.

I realised the name of the library did not conform to Java naming conventions, so changed it a different name, but this had no effect on the generated documentation.